# ko template: getTemplate() after AJAX not working(DOM append)

Tags: ajax, knockout, dom

Page  with products has loading by ajax(infinity scroll loading), response with products are Html page, from  which new products search by class(Jqury) and appended to existing page, as a result is a problem, that some components(that are inside of a products, like counter products in basket) not working after that, because `<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->` are not working and needed template wasn't loaded, i tried `.trigger('contentUpdate')` and `applyBindings()`, but thats not working.
How to make knockout reinitialize himself after apending new DOM elements to existing page?